# Related post is working in single.php file but not in sidebar.php

Tags: wordpress

Related post is working in single.php file but not in sidebar.php. Please let me know how to rectify this issue. Here is my code.Thanks in advance.

```
<ul>
    <?php
        // more news
        $related = get_posts( array( 
        'category__in' => wp_get_post_categories($post->ID), 
        'numberposts' => 6, 
        'post__not_in' => array($post->ID) ) );

        if( $related ) foreach( $related as $post ) {
        setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <li class="clearfix more_news">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="opinion-img">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
            <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
        </li>
        <?php }
        wp_reset_postdata(); 
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Check in sidebar.php `$post->ID` is equal at correctly ID;

Answer (score 0):

Please try `global $post;` top of the code.

Also Change variable name "$post" from following code

```
 if( $related ) foreach( $related as $post ) {
    setup_postdata($post);
```

It might be overriding the `global $post` variable;

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Thanks @Tristup for your comment but still not working. Can you please give me any other reference? I want to get related post from the category which post I have clicked. I don't want to use any plugin either.